# Keeping a navbar from page to page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just started to mess around with web-development and I only have experience on `struts2` development, where I used `sitemesh` to decorate pages. I'm curious about web development and I'd like to start building a site using `twitter bootstrap` only, but I'm not sure on how to keep my navbar from page to page.

I'm kind of lost so... Is there any "good practise" on this issue? I've googled around for some time and found little help on this topic. Shall I create a `HTML` file and "import" it in any way on all of my pages? How do you usually do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your **navbar div** from your `index.html` to a different file, say `navbar.php` and just add this in the line where you removed the navbar:

```
<?php include ('navbar.php'); ?>
```

Make sure to:

1. Rename the extension of your index file from **index.html** to **index.php**.
2. Keep the **navbar.php** in the same directory as your index file. (If you keep it in a different directory, then specify it accordingly in the php code above).

---

**Example:**

If this is your current code:

```
<body>
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
      </div>
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Rest of your page contents-->
    ....
</body>
```

Then just extract the navbar part and move it to a navbar.php file and your index file will look like this now:

```
<body>
      <?php include ('navbar.php'); ?>
      <!--Rest of your page contents-->
      ....
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you,  this is what I was looking for. Awesome work by the way, I've had a peek on your personal website and portfolio :)